# SQL BigQuery - Insert rows with different date-range

Tags: mysql, sql-server, google-bigquery

In my SQL - BigQuery, I have a table with 3 column: Date, ID, Quantity, Price about records of sales.

```
ID   | Date        | Quantity|Price
A123 | 10/30/2010  | 3       |600,000
B567 | 10/30/2010  | 6       |900,000
```

I want to add rows duplicate the ID, Quantity but the Date is continued and price are divided into every month basing on quantity (the number of months), like this

```
ID   | Date        | Quantity|Price
A123 | 10/30/2010  | 3       |200,000
A123 | 11/30/2010  | 3       |200,000
A123 | 12/30/2010  | 3       |200,000
B567 | 10/30/2010  | 6       |150,000
B567 | 11/30/2010  | 6       |150,000
B567 | 12/30/2010  | 6       |150,000
B567 | 01/30/2011  | 6       |150,000
B567 | 02/28/2011  | 6       |150,000
B567 | 03/30/2011  | 6       |150,000
```

I searched some query about while but I don't know how to print the result every loop. Could you please to help me accomplish this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL delta MONTH) date, quantity, price / quantity price
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, quantity - 1)) delta
ORDER BY id, date
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'A123' id, DATE '2010-10-30' date, 3 quantity, 600000 price UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B567', '2010-10-30', 6, 900000 
)
SELECT id, DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL delta MONTH) date, quantity, price / quantity price
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(0, quantity - 1)) delta
ORDER BY id, date
```

with result

```
Row id      date        quantity    price    
1   A123    2010-10-30  3           200000.0     
2   A123    2010-11-30  3           200000.0     
3   A123    2010-12-30  3           200000.0     
4   B567    2010-10-30  6           150000.0     
5   B567    2010-11-30  6           150000.0     
6   B567    2010-12-30  6           150000.0     
7   B567    2011-01-30  6           150000.0     
8   B567    2011-02-28  6           150000.0     
9   B567    2011-03-30  6           150000.0
```